# How do I divide matrix by scalar in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, matrix, division, scalar

just having some issues dividing all the values of a matrix by a scalar using MATLAB.

My code looked like,

```
ncol = length(indpic(1,:)); % ncol = 32
row0 = sum(indpic == 0,2); % 161 * 1 matrix
rowprob0 = 'row0' / 'ncol';
```

But the last line kept causing errors. I tried the following, but none of them worked either,

```
rowprob0 = 'row0' ./ 'ncol';
rowprob0 = 'row0' * (1/('ncol'))';
rowprob0 = 'row0' .* (1/('ncol'))';
```

I also attempted mucking around with this, but to even less avail,

```
ncol = length(indpic(1,:)); % ncol = 32
row0 = sum(indpic == 0,2); % 161 * 1 matrix
id_ncol_1 = eye(ncol,ncol);
id_ncol = (id_ncol_1).*(ncol);
rowprob0 = 'row0' / 'id_ncol';
```

If anyone can help me out, that'd be greatly appreciated :) cheers in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you writing `row0` and `ncol` in quotes? Just divide  `row0` by `ncol` to get the result.

```
ncol = length(indpic(1,:)); % ncol = 32
row0 = sum(indpic == 0,2); % 161 * 1 matrix
rowprob0 = row0/ncol  %or row0./ncol, doesn't make a difference when dividing by a scalar
```

Comment: make sure you understand why it doesn't make a difference when I write `/` or `./` in this case.